# how to include xerces parser in html

Tags: javascript, html, xerces-c

i'm new to this area of programming.

when i click a button on the html page i need to invoke xerces parser so a to get the details of the various elements in the associated xml file. i've written the parser program in C. my questions are:
1) Will I be able to write the parser code in javascript. If so, how will i include the headers i.e. the .hpp files used by the parser.
2) If not how will I link the C file with the html via cgi (i.e. how to convert C into cgi program) so that i display the result on the same html page.

Thanks in advance.